# How to call a function which name is stored in a sql table (VB.net)

Tags: sql, vb.net

Maybe someone of you can help me with that problem.

I have written a background task which gets several workers out of a database.
In the database I added to each worker the name of the function which should get called.

But I am not sure how to call that function from vb.net.

It would be awesome if someone of you can give me a hint :)

thanks
Cheers
Arthur

Answer (score 1):

The namespace System.Reflection has numerous methods that enable this functionality, such as [this one:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

From MSDN, the example in the link above:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class MagicClass
    Private magicBaseValue As Integer 

    Public Sub New()
        magicBaseValue = 9
    End Sub 

    Public Function ItsMagic(preMagic As Integer) As Integer 
        Return preMagic * magicBaseValue
    End Function 
End Class 

Public Class TestMethodInfo
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      ' Get the constructor and create an instance of MagicClass 

      Dim magicType As Type = Type.GetType("MagicClass")
      Dim magicConstructor As ConstructorInfo = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
      Dim magicClassObject As Object = magicConstructor.Invoke(New Object(){})

      ' Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of 100 

      Dim magicMethod As MethodInfo = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic")
      Dim magicValue As Object = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, New Object(){100})

      Console.WriteLine("MethodInfo.Invoke() Example" + vbNewLine)
      Console.WriteLine("MagicClass.ItsMagic() returned: {0}", magicValue)
   End Sub 
End Class
```

' The example program gives the following output:

```
' 
' MethodInfo.Invoke() Example 
' 
' MagicClass.ItsMagic() returned: 900
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a dictionary of delegates in your application code. Store the keys in the database, rather than the function names. When you retrieve the key from the database, look it up in the dictionary and, if present, execute it. You don't want to allow arbitrary methods to be executed based on names stored in a database.

They keys could be strings or integers. I'd prefer the latter just for space savings and ease of lookup, but strings would be easier for debugging, perhaps. So you'd have a dictionary like this:

```
Private m_WorkerDelegates As New Dictionary(Of String, Action)()
```

Somewhere else, you'd fill it up with the available workers:

```
m_WorkerDelegates.Add("worker1", AddressOf WorkerMethod1)
m_WorkerDelegates.Add("worker2", AddressOf WorkerMethod2)
```

And then, when retrieving from the database, you'd look up the method in your dictionary:

```
Public Sub ExecuteWorker(ByVal row As DataRow)
    Dim key As String = CStr(row("worker_key"))

    If Not m_WorkerDelegates.ContainsKey(key) Then
        ' either throw exception or report the error in some more effective way '
        Throw New Exception("Invalid worker key specified")
    End If

    ' actually call the worker method '
    m_WorkerDelegates(key)()
End Sub
```